# Visual Studio 2010 ultimate developer license

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm not quite sure how the Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate licensing works.

How many developers can use Visual Studio in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate?
Is it a single user product? or for as many developers as required?

See buying here :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/subscriptions/buy.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per developer (usually named). There is also volume licensing if you have a lot of dev heads

Answer (score 3):

When you buy the Ultimate license, if you don't have some sort of corporate subscription, the price you see on the site is a per-developer cost.

Ultimate is expensive. My advice would be to look over what it gives you versus what your team needs and decide from there. Depending on the work you're doing, Professional may be enough (I don't typically advise going lower).

Answer (score 1):

This is a single user product. There's a separate page for volume licensing: http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/default.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Here is a whitepaper that describes more about the licensing process of Visual Studio, published in September of 2010:

From the link:

> This white paper provides an overview of the Visual Studio 2010 product line, including MSDN subscriptions, and the licensing requirements for those products in common deployment scenarios.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2b1504e6-0bf1-46da-be0e-85cc792c6b9d&displaylang=en